# Formatting text file in form $number/t$q/t$a in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to format the text file so that it indexes the number of the questions. The code I have so far is:

```
my %questions = map { split(/\t/, $_, 2) } @qa_list;
```

This correctly formats the data into a list of questions/answer, separated by a tab. However, I cannot figure out how to modify this so that it numbers the questions. I'm thinking of nesting another split() or map in there, but I wind up with convoluted expressions that don't work and are difficult to read.

EDIT: In response to the first comment

The output, currently, would be this:

```
Question1\tAnswer1
Question2\tAnswer2
Question3\tAnswer3
```

But I want it to be:

```
1    Question1\tAnswer1
2    Question2\tAnswer2
3    Question3\tAnswer3
```

Comment: Questions like these work best when you can provide example input and the expected output for that input. With the given information as of this moment, I am not quite sure what you want.

Comment: Did you mean `\t` instead of `/t`? You should probably not try and print literal escape sequences in output samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to take an array containing

```
Question 1<tab>Answer 1
Question 2<tab>Answer 2
...
```

and print out

```
1<tab>Question 1<tab>Answer 1
2<tab>Question 2<tab>Answer 2
...
```

so it's simply a question of adding the array index plus one and a tab to the front.

```
print "$_\t$qa_list[$_-1]\n" for 1..@qa_list;
```

Comment: This ```print```s the default variable ```$_``` (which will be a number from 0 to ```$#qa_list``` - i.e. the length of the list) and then the element of the list in the position  of that number.  The first question will be numbered "0" which is good if the Q/A are from a computer science exam. Otherwise, this pithy one-liner may need more "characters". +1 for short but sweet :-)

Comment: ```print "$_\t$qa_list[$_]\n", $_+1 for 0..$#qa_list;```

Comment: @G.Cito `use feature 'say'; $, = "\t"; say $_+1, $qa_list[$_] for keys @qa_list;`

Comment: @TLP, Why use `$,` instead of `join`??? In this case, concatenation is even simpler!

Comment: Indeed, and that's why I used that solution in my answer. This was a comment to G. Cito for the pure TIMTOWTDI.

Comment: @TLP :-)  I love little  features like ```say```: 
```say $_."\t " , $qa_list[$_] for keys @qa_list```  \o/

Answer (score 2):

At its simplest:

```
my $count = 1;             # start index at 1
for (@qa_list) {
    print $count++,        # increase counter
          "\t$_\n";        # join with tab end with newline
}
```

Comment: So, would I put this before or after my other text? I do not know how to integrate it.

Comment: It does not matter where you put it, as long as you do not alter the array. To integrate it, declare the hash before the loop and assign to it inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

ikegami's answer has an off-by-one error you can fix using `printf`

```
printf "%s\t%s\n", $_+1, $qa_list[$_] for 0..$#qa_list;
```

or

```
print ($_+1)."\t$qa_list[$_]\n" for 0..$#qa_list;
```

Comment: I have fixed the problem with my answer.